# {PYTHON} getting error while using pytube in python

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

**HTTP Error 410: Gone**
i am getting the above error while executing the code

The code is given below :

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = input("Enter the url : ")
yt = YouTube(url)
streams = yt.streams
streams.download()
```

I am trying to download a YouTube video using pytube

Comment: What `url` do you provide?

Comment: As is your code leads to `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 6, in <module>
    streams.download()
AttributeError: 'StreamQuery' object has no attribute 'download'`, however with `streams[0].download()` I do not notice any issue with latest pip version that is 15.0.0 on Linux Mint.